# Making zip file with custom content per user

Tags: python, django

What I tried to do:

1. In my main project folder I have directory `downloadable_app` with these files/folders inside:

   - index.html
   - js/app.f54b97d7097bcf4226c0.js
2. I need to allow users to download this `downloadable_app` folder as zip archive
3. In `app.f54b97d7097bcf4226c0.js` file I have `axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer <BEARER_TOKEN>'`
4. I need to replace `<BEARER_TOKEN>` by `request.user` token

This is how I did this:

**settings.py:**

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))
DOWNLOADABLE_APP_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'downloadable_app')
```

**views.py:**

```
import datetime
import binascii
import os
from datetime import timedelta
import shutil
...

from oauth2_provider.models import Application, AccessToken


class DownloadAppView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.request.user.plan:
            raise Http404
        self.token = self._get_or_create_user_token()
        return super(DownloadAppView, self).dispatch(
            request, *args, **kwargs)

    def _add_token_to_downloadable_app(self, token):
        with open(os.path.join(settings.DOWNLOADABLE_APP_ROOT, 'js/app.f54b97d7097bcf4226c0.js'), 'r') as file:
            filedata = file.read()

        filedata = filedata.replace('<BEARER_TOKEN>', token)

        with open(os.path.join(settings.DOWNLOADABLE_APP_ROOT, 'js/app.f54b97d7097bcf4226c0.js'), 'w') as file:
            file.write(filedata)

    def _reset_token_in_downloadable_app(self, token):
        with open(os.path.join(settings.DOWNLOADABLE_APP_ROOT, 'js/app.f54b97d7097bcf4226c0.js'), 'r') as file:
            filedata = file.read()

        filedata = filedata.replace(token, '<BEARER_TOKEN>')

        with open(os.path.join(settings.DOWNLOADABLE_APP_ROOT, 'js/app.f54b97d7097bcf4226c0.js'), 'w') as file:
            file.write(filedata)

    def _get_or_create_user_token(self):
        app, created = Application.objects.get_or_create(
            client_type=Application.CLIENT_CONFIDENTIAL,
            authorization_grant_type=Application.GRANT_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS,
            redirect_uris='https://www.example.com/',
            name='downloadable_app',
            user=User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True, is_staff=True).first()
        )
        access_token, created = AccessToken.objects.get_or_create(
            user=self.request.user,
            scope='read write',
            application=app,
            defaults={'expires': timezone.now() + timedelta(days=1000), 'token': binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(20)).decode()}
        )
        return access_token.token

    def get(self, request):
        self._add_token_to_downloadable_app(self.token)

        # create_zip_archive
        shutil.make_archive('downloadable_app_archives/my_app_{}'.format(request.user.pk), 'zip', settings.DOWNLOADABLE_APP_ROOT)
        response = HttpResponse(
            open(os.path.join(
                settings.PROJECT_PATH, 'downloadable_app_archives/my_app_{}.zip'.format(request.user.pk)), 'rb').read(), content_type='application/zip')
        self._reset_token_in_downloadable_app(self.token)
        return response
```

**management.commands.delete_zip_archives.py:**

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Delete downloadable app zip archives'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_PATH, 'downloadable_app_archives'))
```

Can you please take a look and let me know how can I improve this?